# How to disable Windows Defender

Tags: windows-11, windows-defender

I tried to add DisableAntiSpyware in the registry which works OK but only until a reboot.

Bear in mind that I don't want to disable all Defender features, just the real-time protection permanently (like DisableAntiSpyware would do).

In Windows 11 Pro the method of disabling Defender in Group Policy Editor also doesn't work as the setting gets overridden on restart.

There's this app called Defender Control, it WORKS even after a reboot, but isn't there any more elegant solution? Like a registry edit?

Comment: Simplest way is to install a different AV product

Comment: But I don't want any AV. The PC is my second one and I'm using it just for fun, there's nothing important in it and Defender just takes its RAM and slows it down a bit.

Comment: There is no true way to disable or remove Windows Defender, the only way it was designed to be suspended, is if a compatible AV is installed.  Any method, that involves forcefully removing it, on Windows 10 will work on Windows 11 21H2.

Answer (score 1):

> isn't there any more elegant solution? Like a registry edit?

Yes – my solution is to rename the registry key
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend` to
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend-BLOCKED!!`
(for example).
To learn how, read on.

##### DISCLAIMERS

I have tried my solution on Windows 10 only, but I suggest you try it
on Windows 11 to see if it works there too.

> I don't want to disable all Defender features, just the real time
> protection permanently

My method completely and permanently disables *all* Windows Defender
antivirus features (on Windows 10).

If you want to keep the opportunity to scan the hard drive for
viruses at any time, one alternative would be to download and run
the [Microsoft Safety Scanner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/safety-scanner-download).
<sup>1</sup>

#### 1. Renaming the registry key requires a restart in *Safe mode*

As far as I know, the registry key
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend` cannot be renamed
starting windows normally.

To start in *Safe mode*, press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type
`msconfig` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In the **System Configuration** window that opens, click the **Boot**
tab, and then check **Safe boot** as shown in the screenshot below.
Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and then press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
followed by <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>u</kbd> to shut down.
Once the computer has turned off, press the physical power button to
turn it on again.
<sup>2</sup>
This will start your computer in *Safe mode*.

[image: System Configuration > Boot > Safe boot > Apply.]

#### 2. In *Safe mode*, rename the registry key

Once you have entered *Safe mode*, open the registry editor –  press
<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` and hit
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Right-click the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend` key
and rename it to `WinDefend-BLOCKED!!`.

[image: Block Windows Defender by renaming the 'WinDefend' key.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

*That's it!*
All that remains is to leave the *Safe mode* and restart normally.
Use the same procedure as before (`msconfig`) – but this time
*uncheck* **Safe boot** before restarting.

#### 3. Defender Control

I assume the *Defender Control* you refer to is
[this one](https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v2-1/)?

Software that tampers with Windows Defender will inevitably be judged
as harmful.

Thus, it shouldn't surprise anyone that 57 of 71 security vendors at
[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1ef6c1a4dfdc39b63bfe650ca81ab89510de6c0d3d7c608ac5be80033e559326/community)
flag it as malicious.

As one comment puts it :
*It is safe to use if you want to disable defender by yourself, but it
may be used to disable protection for easier malware spreading.*

[image: At VirusTotal, 57 vendors flag Defender Control as malicious.]

#### 4. Other possible solutions?

I've searched the internet quite a bit for other solutions.

[This page](https://www.alitajran.com/turn-off-windows-defender-in-windows-10-permanently/)
by Ali Tajran has heavily inspired my solution in sections 1 and 2
above.

Other than that, I haven't found *any* solution that doesn't involve
starting the computer in *Safe mode*, except to install some other
antivirus software to replace Windows Defender.
<sup>3</sup>

### References

- [Download page for the Microsoft Safety Scanner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/safety-scanner-download)
- [Download page for *Defender Control*](https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v2-1/)
- [VirusTotal verdict of *Defender Control*](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1ef6c1a4dfdc39b63bfe650ca81ab89510de6c0d3d7c608ac5be80033e559326/community)
- [Turn off Windows Defender in Windows 10 permanently](https://www.alitajran.com/turn-off-windows-defender-in-windows-10-permanently/)

---

<sup>1</sup>
This is what I do. – Once a year, or once every two years I run the
*quick scan* of the Microsoft Safety Scanner, just to ascertain
that I don't have any viruses.
I cannot recommend running the *full scan*.
The Microsoft Safety Scanner doesn't come with automatic updates, so
if this is important to you, then my solution might not be what you
want.

<sup>2</sup>
This is slightly more circumstantial than just pressing *Restart*, but
on my laptop (which has an HDD) it's considerably faster.

<sup>3</sup>
I have no interest in such a "solution".

Answer (score 0):

The Group Policy method works fine on Windows 11. However you first need to open the Windows Defender UI and disable Tamper Protection.